# $a^2 + b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ and $p \nmid a, b$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

Let $p$ be a prime number such that $p \not\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$. Show that there exist two integers $a$ and $b$, such that $a^2 + b^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ and $p \nmid a, b$.

If $p \not\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ and $p$ is prime, $p$ must be of the form $4k+1$. But I don't know how to continue the problem. Can you help me, please? Thanks!

Comment: We can do a bit better than $a^2 + b^2 \equiv 0\pmod p$. For primes of the form $4k + 1$, we can find $a$ and $b$ so that $a^2 + b^2 = p$. See [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares)

Comment: Use `\nmid` rather than `\not |`

Comment: @PraneetSrivastava Although that is usually considered a deeper result. So it depends on what level this problem is meant for.

Comment: @Arthur That is true. Although Euler's proof is elementary, if long. There's a much nicer way to prove this using the result the OP asks for - using that $\mathbb Z [i]$ is a UFD.

Comment: Quadratic residue(prime modulus) from wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue#Prime_modulus) "If p ≡ 1 (mod 4) the negative of a residue modulo p is a residue and the negative of a nonresidue is a nonresidue.

If p ≡ 3 (mod 4) the negative of a residue modulo p is a nonresidue and the negative of a nonresidue is a residue.".  That *is* precisely this statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true because $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. So there exist $x$ s.t.

$$x^2 \equiv -1 \pmod p \implies x^2 + 1^2 \equiv 0\pmod p$$

Hence the proof.

---

To prove that such an element exist we can use Wilson's Theorem. We then have $(p-1)! \equiv - 1 \pmod p$. Now use $p-k \equiv -k \pmod p$ and do this change for the numbers greater than $\frac{p-1}{2}$. Since you have even number of such factors the minus signs cancel out and you will have:

$$\left[\left( \frac{p-1}{2} \right)!\right]^2 \equiv - 1 \pmod p$$